# Batch File - Capture the Time Down to the Second into a Variable

Tags: batch-file

How would I capture the time down the second into a variable using a batch file. My script right now looks like this.

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF

set yy=%date:~-4%
set mm=%date:~-7,2%
set dd=%date:~-10,2%
set newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy%

echo %newdate%
```

I've captured the date, and it prints exactly what I need, but now I need to append the time to the variable. How would I do it?

Comment: If `%date%` is the date, perhaps `%time%` is the time?

Comment: How would I get it down to the second and append it?

Comment: Append it by & symbol....see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
set yy=%date:~-4%
set dd=%date:~-7,2%
set mm=%date:~-10,2%
set newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy%_%Time:~0,8%
set newdate=%newdate::=%
echo %newdate%
pause
```

Comment: You still need your other code. Just replace the line I originally showed. I edited my answer.

Comment: If you could, it's almost perfect, can you make so that the time doesn't have the colon? so its  131510 instead of 13:15:10

Comment: Added 1 line to my answer to remove :

Comment: Of course this mechanism only works for the date format you have your computer set to. It would not give the desired results for computers in many other countries.

Comment: One more thing, and then I'll drop it. Right now, it displays MM:DD:YYYYY, how do I alter it, so that it's DD:MM:YYYY? How would I alter my code?

Comment: Ahhhh... original code was wrong. Had Month and Day swapped. Try my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Read the time into a variable first to get a snapshot so that it doesn't keep ticking while you're extracting the fields.  Then use the `set` substring operators to extract what you want.

The time has the format `HH:MM:SS.MS` (at least in my en-us locale).  One gotcha is that the hour field might start with a leading space, so you need an `if` condition to change it to a leading zero or to remove the space.

```
set "current_time=%time%"

set "hour=%current_time:~0,2%"
if "%current_time:~0,1%"==" " set "hour=0%current_time:~1,1%"
set "min=%current_time:~3,2%"
set "sec=%current_time:~6,2%"
set "ms=%current_time:~-2%"

set "newtime=%hour% %min% %sec% %ms%"

echo %newtime%
```

If you want to remove the front space in the hour instead of changing it to a leading zero, then you'd do this instead:

```
set "hour=%current_time:~0,2%"
if "%current_time:~0,1%"==" " set "hour=%current_time:~1,1%"
```

Comment: How would I do it so that the time doesn't contain the colon?

Comment: @Nexusfactor:  I don't understand.  On my system, `%newtime%` does not contain any colons.

Comment: But my code puts spaces between numbers in `newtime`, so that's impossible.  Even if it were parsing incorrectly, we'd still see the spaces:  `set "newtime=%hour% %min% %sec% %ms%"`.  Are you sure you are running the correct batch file and printing the correct `%newtime%` variable?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF

set yy=%date:~-4%
set mm=%date:~-7,2%
set dd=%date:~-10,2%
set newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy% & time /T

echo %newdate%
pause
```

You can run multiple commands by adding the `&` symbol. If you wish to only append time, if the first command suceed, use `&&` instead.

Comment: Close, bare with me. It displays the time above the date(2 lines). I want to use this variable as the name of a folder. How would I capture it into one line?

Comment: Thanks Remember, I need to it down to the second.